# replace a word in subtitle with ffmpeg

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

I want to use ffmpeg to replace all occurrences of a word in all  subtitles of a video file with ffmpeg. All non-subtitles channels should be copied (not reencoded) and all formatting from the original subtitles should stay if possible.

example:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -SUBTITLEFILER='old_word/new_word' output.mkv
```

I am using ubuntu 19.04 and bash (in case additional steps or dependencies would be required for this)

Answer (score 2):

`ffmpeg` has no find/replace functionality for subtitles, but you can do this losslessly in 3 commands:

1. Extract the subtitles:

   ```
   ffmpeg -i input.mkv -map 0:s:0 -c copy sub0.ass -map 0:s:1 -c copy sub1.ass -map 0:s:2 -c copy sub2.ass
   ```

   I'm assuming your subtitles are SubStation Alpha (ASS/SSA) subtitles. Use the appropriate output name if they differ: such as `.srt` for SubRip (refer to `ffmpeg -muxers`).
2. Replace with `sed`:

   ```
   sed -i 's/cat/dog/g' *.ass
   ```
3. Remux:

   ```
   ffmpeg -i input.mkv -i sub0.ass -i sub1.ass -i sub2.ass -map 0 -map -0:s -map 1 -map 2 -map 3 -c copy -metadata:s:s:0 language=fas -metadata:s:s:1 language=eng -metadata:s:s:2 language=fin output.mkv
   ```

If you want to make a certain subtitle the default see the `-disposition` option as shown in [`ffmpeg` set subtitles track as default](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26956762/).